# API call in PWA on Microsoft Edge browser does not work

Tags: angular, browser, httpclient, microsoft-edge, progressive-web-apps

I am using Angular 5 in PWA to make an API call (`HttpClient`). Though it is working fine on Chrome, it is not working on Microsoft Edge browser.

I have tried with `HttpClient, Http`. I have checked for `Promises, Observables`, but, no luck!

I am getting below error on Edge browser:

`{"_body":{},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}`

Some help would be really appreciable!

Comment: Does it contain any error message? What your Edge browser version? I have tested [the angular document live example](https://v5.angular.io/guide/http) on my side (using the Edge browser 42.17134.1.0 version), it seems that everything works well. You could check [the example code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aqdqplneypb).

Comment: Thanks Zhi Lv - MSFT for your reply.
My browser details are:
`Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134`
The example you have given is not a pwa, I guess. Please correct me, if I am wrong.